# How to initialize a two dimensional array in python

Tags: python

I want to implement an adjacency list representation of a graph in python (for educational purposes, I am not trying to reinvent the wheel :-) )

Every vertex points to an array of edges. I want them to be initialized so that I can perform `append` instantly.

So I wrote:

```
self.vertices = [[]] * size
```

But this does not work because I am getting the same list object duplicated, so when I write

```
self.vertices[v1].append(edge_index)
```

this number is appended to all (or the only) array

How may I perform the list initialization in an elegant fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
self.vertices = [[] for _ in range(size)]
```

#### Example

```
size = 5

a = [[] for _ in range(size)]
a[2].append(5)

>>> print a
[[], [], [5], [], []]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class adj_matrix:
    def add_data(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.vertices = [[] for i in range(self.size)]
        # append a single value
        self.vertices[1].append(5)
        # append a dict
        self.vertices[2].append({'a':2})
        # append a list
        self.vertices[3].append([1,2,3])

        self.vertices[4].append((1,2));
        print self.vertices

mat = adj_matrix()
mat.add_data()
```

Add data according to your needs.

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[], [5], [{'a': 2}], [[1, 2, 3]], [(1, 2)], [], [], [], [], []]
```